# How to fix bootstrap dropdown z-index in the backside of a flipped div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flip

I have multiple divs which can be flipped on hover via css transformation.
On each backside I have a bootstrap buttongroup with a dropdown button.
If I expand the dropdown-menu the list is hiding behind the next div.

[image]

How can I bring the list to the front?

http://www.bootply.com/3ugZnOsnY2

Comment: i came up with this http://www.bootply.com/64HpGS3Smh i know it is not up to  the mark

Answer (score 0):

Just listen for bootstraps dropdown events and then adjust the elements z-index. Check the snippet, you should choose a bit more precise selectors than i did though.

```js
$('.flip').hover(function(){
  $(this).find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
});

$('.btn-group').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
  $(this).parentsUntil($( ".face", ".back")).css('zIndex', 200);
})

$('.btn-group').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
  $(this).parentsUntil($( ".face", ".back")).css('zIndex', 0);
})
```

```css
body{
  padding-top:50px;
  background: #555;
}
.flip {
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
perspective: 800;

    position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}
.flip .card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
    transform: rotatey(-180deg);
}
.flip .card {

  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.flip .card .face {

  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden ;
    backface-visibility: hidden ;
  z-index: 2;
   
}
.flip .card .front {
  position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;

}
.flip .card .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
    transform: rotatey(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="flip">
          <div class="card">

            <div class="face front">
              <div class="well well-sm"> Front</div>
            </div>

            <div class="face back">
              <div class="well well-sm">
              Back
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">1</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">2</button>
                  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      Dropdown
                      <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link 1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="flip">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="face front">
              <div class="well well-sm"> Front</div>
            </div>

            <div class="face back">
              <div class="well well-sm">
              Back
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">1</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">2</button>
                  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      Dropdown
                      <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link 1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Have fun!